# How to use DATETime Column in dynamic query in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a Stored Proc which is using for Search Applicants is written as below:

```
 /*  
AUTHOR   :   
CREATION DATE  :      
NOTES   :  
PURPOSE   :   
MODIFIED BY  :  
MODIFICATION DATE :  
*/  
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_GET_ApplicantByFilter  
(  
 @ApplicantName  VARCHAR(100)='Ram',  
 @AgeFrom  INT=0,  
 @AgeTo   INT=0,  
 @Experience  INT=0,  
 @ExperienceMonths  INT=0,  
 @City   VARCHAR(100)='',  
 @QualificationID INT=0,  
 @PositionID  INT=0,  
 @ApplyDateFrom  DATETIME='2010-06-29 00:00:00.000',  
 @ApplyDateTo  DATETIME=NULL,
 @SortColumn Varchar(128)='ApplicantID',  
@SortDirection Varchar(56)='desc',  
@Page int=1,  
@RecsPerPage int   =10
)  
AS
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)                              
DECLARE @DSQL VARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @whereCondition VARCHAR(1024)                              
DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int                              
SET @FirstRec = (@Page - 1) * @RecsPerPage                              
SET @LastRec = (@Page * @RecsPerPage + 1)  
Declare @SectionCount int;  
Set NoCount On  
Begin  
 SET @SQL='Select  ROW_NUMBER() over( order by '+@SortColumn + ' ' +@SortDirection +') rownum, tblApplicants.ApplicantID, tblApplicants.ApplicantName, tblApplicants.FatherName, tblApplicants.DateOfBirth,  tblApplicants.QualificationID,  tblApplicants.EMailID, tblApplicants.Address, tblApplicants.City, tblApplicants.State, tblApplicants.Phone,
 tblApplicants.ApplyDate, tblApplicants.PositionID, tblApplicants.isActive,  tblPositionMaster.PositionName 
FROM tblApplicants INNER JOIN tblPositionMaster ON tblApplicants.PositionID = tblPositionMaster.PositionID 
WHERE 1=1 AND tblApplicants.isActive=1  '
if @ApplicantName!=''
begin
  SET @sql +=' AND tblApplicants.ApplicantName like ''%'+ @ApplicantName +'%'''
end
if @AgeFrom!=0
begin
SET @SQL+=' AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,tblApplicants.DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) >= '+@AgeFrom
end
 if @AgeTo!=0
 begin
SET @SQL+=' AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,tblApplicants.DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) <= '+@AgeTo
 end
if @ApplyDateFrom IS NOT NULL
begin
SET @SQL+= ' AND CONVERT(DATETIME,tblApplicants.ApplyDate,101) ='+ CONVERT(DATETIME,@ApplyDateFrom,101)
end
SET @DSQL ='SELECT  * from (' + @SQL +') AS tbl'                              
  print @DSQL  
DECLARE @TEMPResult TABLE(RowNum INT,       
   ApplicantID int,                
ApplicantName varchar(100),  
FatherName varchar(200),  
DateOfBirth DATETIME,  
QualificationID int,  
EMailID varchar(200),  
Address varchar(200),  
City varchar(200),  
State varchar(200),  
Phone varchar(200),  
ApplyDate DATETIME,
PositionID int,
isActive int,
PositionName varchar(200)
)
     INSERT INTO @TEMPResult EXEC(@DSQL)  
SELECT (Select Count(*) from @TEMPResult) as Count, * FROM @TEMPResult WHERE RowNum > @FirstRec AND RowNum < @LastRec   
RETURN            
END
```

i want to apply "**=>**" and "**<=**" operators on ApplyDate. every time i got "****Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.***
*"

please help me how can apply these operators on ApplDate

Comment: Use Datediff instead ">="

Comment: @vikas can you please show me any example

Comment: what is the type of column `tblApplicants.ApplyDate`

Comment: @vikas it is of DATETIME

Comment: try replacing `CONVERT(DATETIME,tblApplicants.ApplyDate,101) ='+ CONVERT(DATETIME,@ApplyDateFrom,101)`   with 'DATEDIFF(DD,tblApplicants.ApplyDate, ' + @ApplyDateFrom + ') = 0'

Comment: @vikas still the same error

Comment: What is the format of @ApplyDateFrom?

Comment: @VenkatRenukaPrasad i am using the format for comparing the dates

Comment: @VenkatRenukaPrasad it is `datetime`

Comment: my bad, I didn't see that. convert @ApplyDateFrom to nvarchar, why do you convert it to datetime?

Comment: @VenkatRenukaPrasad actually i want to apply >= and <= operators on these i cannot apply these to string values

Comment: May be some rows in your table tblApplicants, have an invalid format for ApplyDate..

Comment: @raman after this line change what query was printing ?`DATEDIFF(DD,tblApplicants.ApplyDate, ' + @ApplyDateFrom + ') = 0`

Comment: no dear ............ that's not the issue.. @VenkatRenukaPrasad

Comment: @raman your concatenation have issue just use `CAST(@ApplyDateFrom as varchar)`

Comment: use `DATEDIFF(DD,tblApplicants.ApplyDate, ' + CAST(@ApplyDateFrom as varchar) + ') = 0 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @SQL+= ' AND CONVERT(DATETIME,tblApplicants.ApplyDate,101) ='+ CONVERT(DATETIME, @ApplyDateFrom, 101)
```

change it to:

```
SET @SQL+= ' AND CONVERT(DATETIME, tblApplicants.ApplyDate, 101) = CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' + cast(@ApplyDateFrom as nvarchar) + ''', 101)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,tblApplicants.ApplyDate,101) ='+ CONVERT(DATETIME,@ApplyDateFrom,101)
```

Updated

```
AND DATEDIFF(DD,tblApplicants.ApplyDate, CAST(''' + CAST(@ApplyDateFrom as varchar) + ''' as datetime)) = 0
```

for more look this query

```
DECLARE @ApplyDateFrom  DATETIME='2010-06-29 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @QUERY varchar(max)
SET @QUERY =
'SELECT  DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE(), CAST(''' + CAST(@ApplyDateFrom as varchar) + ''' as datetime))'
PRINT @QUERY
```

Answer (score 0):

`@AgeFrom` is an `int`. You need to convert it to a varchar before concatentating it to a string.

```
  'AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,tblApplicants.DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) >= '+convert(varchar(5),@AgeFrom)
```

Not that this will work, of course, as `datediff(year...` won't give you an age. eg:

```
 select DATEDIFF(YEAR,'2000-12-25','2013-10-01')
```

will return 13, not 12.

Similarly for `ApplyDate` convert that to a string

```
  CONVERT(DATE,tblApplicants.ApplyDate,101) = ''' + CONVERT(varchar(20),@ApplyDateFrom,111) + ''''
```

To be honest though, this whole approach looks like a bad idea to me.

Comment: please i want to apply the check for "Apply Date", please suggest me for that particular column

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make sure the parameter before it come into your stored procedured is in this format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

then you're save to compare using "<=" and ">=" and doesn't need to convert it to other format just compare like this

```
tblApplicants.ApplyDate >='2013-10-01 18:00:00'
```

You need to cast applydate to string before concatenate to dynamics sql.

Mean
SET @SQL+= ' AND CONVERT(DATETIME,tblApplicants.ApplyDate,101) ='+ cast (CONVERT(DATETIME,@ApplyDateFrom,101)   AS VARCHAR)